# Prove that structure M is not Herbrand structure

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I've been trying to solve the following problem, but I get a bit confused with the solution I get.

Here's the problem:
Let's *M* be a structure with an universe all the terms with no variables. We know that the value of the term *f(x)* in M given evaluation *v* is *v(x)*.
Prove that *M* is not Herbrand structure.

My attempt to prove it:

By definition structure *H* is Herbrand if for every functional symbol *f* and elements of the Universe (which contains only terms with no variables)

$t_1, ... , t_n$ we have that $f^H(t_1, ...,t_n)=f(t_1,...,t_n)$
On the other hand we know evaluation functions are functions mapping elements of the Universe to variables.

So
$[\![f(x)]\!]^Hv=$*(by definition of evaluation)*$=f^H([\![x]\!]^Hv)=f^H(v(x))$

On the other hand we want

$f^H(x)=f(x)$ By the definition of Herbrand structure.
So here I get confused by the fact that the evalution *v* may be such that *v(x)=x*.
Any suggestions how to prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S$ be a set of formulas (more exactly : *clauses*).

Let $H$ the *Herbrand universe* of $S$ (the domain of all *ground* (i.e. closed) terms) and $I$ an interpretation of $S$ over $H$.

In order that $I$ is an *Herbrand model* of $S$ we need that :

> 1) $I$ maps all constants in $S$ to themselves;
>
> 2) If $f$ is an $n$-place function symbol and $h_1, \ldots, h_n$ are elements of $H$, then $I$ must assign to $f$ a function $f^{H}$ that maps $(h_1, \ldots, h_n)$ to 
>   $f^H(h_1, \ldots, h_n)$ (an element of $H$).

But the variable $x$ is not in the Herbrand universe $H$, because it is not a *closed* term.

Thus, $v(x)$ is an element of the domain $D$ of the *structure* $\mathcal M$, and again $v(x)$ is not an element of $H$.

Comment: Thank you! Clear and simple explanation!

Comment: @Zarrie - you are welcome :-)